DIN rail end stops and question about orientation
I just had a fit of rage and have decided I hate this style of DIN end stop. I've over tightened and broken them countless times and they still slide down the rail with a little bit of force even when screwed down tightly.

What are the alternatives?
I had a quick look and found this alternative style, has anyone used them and are they any good?

Also while I'm here, is there a correct convention for which way is up when mounting things on DIN rails?
I figure if the device has clips you pull with a flat blade to get them off, they should probably go on the bottom.
And the end stop I've shown and hate, the long bit of plastic furthest from the two screws, should be at the top.
Or does it not matter at all?
Thanks so much

The orientation depends on the marking you put in them.
There is no convention, it even changes within a brand. Just look at ABB circuit breakers for example. (SZ201 down, SN201 up)
Those E/UK are best tightened with an electric screwdriver (cordless drill) because they need to be tight. Use the correct screw, they're made for different types of rail.
If I recall correctly, the screw that drives a point into the rail is for standard TS-35.
The drawback of parts like this is they don't come with instructions.
If you don't want to use electric tools you can also use clips like the
CLIPFIX 35-5, they do not require further tools. But are more difficult to remove/adjust.

Thanks. You ever tried the Wago end stops? https://www.wago.com/au/accessories/screwless-end-stop/p/249-116

@totalconfusion no, looks similar to clipfix35-5
